# Including milliseconds in a Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, python

```
            sudo hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\n"' /dev/ttyUSB0 | awk '$1=="ed" {
            getline byte1
            getline byte2
            number = strtonum("0x" substr(byte2,2,1))+2
            data =" ::ED." byte1"."byte2
            while(number-->0)
            {getline byte; data = data"."byte}
            print data"."
            }' |  tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'| grep -v '^.....00'
```

I am running this small script and I am trying to attach timestamp to each line in milliseconds (that should be a realtime value) and not a static value for all the lines. I am expecting an output like this ,

:: 144146 ::ED.data

:: 144146 ::ED.data

:: 144146 ::ED.data

Instead of 144146 in each line I should get Milliseconds value and the values should be different. I have a python script for what I am looking for

import time

```
 def timestamp():
      now = time.time()
      localtime = time.localtime(now)
      milliseconds = '%03d' % int((now - int(now)) * 1000)
      return time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime) + milliseconds
      value = timestamp()
      print value
```

Is there anyway that I could implement the same in my script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you use two non-portable things:

- GNU awk's two-way I/O (see [relevant StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960911/2350060));
- millisecond output with `date` (see this [ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/588705)).

With that, you can prefix the input with timestamps like that:

```
awk '{"date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%3N" |& getline timestamp;
      print timestamp,$0;
      close("date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%3N")}'
```

(Note that that `close` is mandatory, and the string there should match the command you run on line 1. See aforementioned SO answer for details.)

Incorporating that into your program, you'll get:

```
sudo hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\n"' /dev/ttyUSB0 | awk '$1=="ed" {
getline byte1
getline byte2
number = strtonum("0x" substr(byte2,2,1))+2
"date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%3N" |& getline timestamp;
data = timestamp " ::ED." byte1"."byte2
close("date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%3N")
while(number-->0)
{getline byte; data = data"."byte}
print data"."
}' |  tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'| grep -v '^.....00'
```